# Angular2 how to hide empty array in POST

Tags: angular, typescript

In my filters I have products list. I want to send this array only, when there are some elements. Is it possible?

Request function:

```
getRecipes(page, pageSize, filters){
let body = JSON.stringify({ "size": pageSize, "page": page, "listOfFilters": filters});
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/cookbook/recipe/filter',body,options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());}
```

Filter Class:

```
export class Filter{
    products = new Array<String>();
    rating: {[key: string]:string} = {};
    level: {[key: string]:string} = {};
}
```

Now JSON looks like:

```
{"size":10,"page":1,"listOfFilters":{"products":[],"rating":{"from":"1","to":"5"},"level":{"from":"1"
,"to":"5"}}}
```

And I want it to looks like (when products list is empty):

```
{"size":10,"page":1,"listOfFilters":{"rating":{"from":"1","to":"5"},"level":{"from":"1"
    ,"to":"5"}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, how you want the endresult to look like, but this is a simple if condition, where you can leverage [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

```
if (filters.products.length == 0) {
    delete filters.products;
}

let body = JSON.stringify({ "size": pageSize, "page": page, "listOfFilters": filters });
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about 2 more "maps" in Filter class.

Comment: Maybe care to explain in your post what the endresult should look like? Because this comment doesn't tell my, why my answer doesn't help you :)

Comment: See my updated answer - you can use `delete` for that.